# Which is most secure stateless authentication method? JWT does not satisfy the requirements of the application

Tags: security, authentication, encryption, jwt, stateless

My primary concern is to do not allow any attacker to compromise the token even if the attacker has access to the application code(secret key) or the database. And I don't want the users to log in from multiple devices at a time.

Here the front-end applications would be on Android/iPhone. While backend application would use PHP.

Edit: I prefer not to store the whole token in the database. Maybe we can store some small encrypted string which can be appended to the token.

Comment: Can you describe why you think that JWT doesn't satisfy the requirements? What are the exact requirements? I only see two of them: 1. stateless 2. no session compromise when server is pwned. Are there others?

Comment: @ArtjomB.
1. I need to be sure that the user should not be able to log in from multiple devices at a time. In this case, if I use JWT, I won't be able to check if the user is already logged in or not.

2. If an attacker gets the secret key, It would be easy for the attacker to compromise the token. (here an attacker can be an unethical person who has developed the application, someone who is maintaining the server, or some hacker)

Comment: If the application server is breached, there is no way to protect against session hijacking or even new session creation without creating another server that is only responsible for authenticating users and checking session tokens. This auth server then must be assumed to not be breachable. If the application server was breached then it is likely that the auth server will be breached too. You haven't described how many servers you have and what kind of roles they play between each other.

Comment: Okay. I am having a single server.

Comment: Then there is **no** secure way to do this. You could drift into security through obscurity (i.e. obfuscating source code), but this only slows the attacker down and doesn't prevent exploitation.

Comment: Okay. @ArtjomB. Thank you for the help.